# В чем ошибки и почему код не работает?

Tags: python

Задание:
Элементами множества А являются натуральные числа. Известно, что выражение:

```
¬(¬(x ∈ A) ∧ (x ∈ {3, 6, 9, 12})) ∨ ¬(x ∈ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6})
```

истинно (т. е. принимает значение 1) при любом значении переменной х. Определите наименьшее возможное количество элементов множества A.

Мой код:

```
x1=[3,6,9,12]
x2=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
for a in range (1,1000):
    i=0
    for x in range (1,1000):
        if not(not(x in a) and (x in x2)) or not(x in x2):
            i=1
            print (a)
            break
```

Ошибка:

```
i=not(not(x in a) and (x in x2)) or not(x in x2)
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

Ответ который должен получиться: 2

Comment: Для оператора in правый аргумент должен быть итерируемым объектом (например, списком), а у вас справа число.

Comment: Эта задача решается головой и руками (руки не очень нужны, голова всё-таки нужна). Программировать тут не надо.

Comment: @insolor а что мне нужно сделать?

Comment: @insolor тогда получается 1

Comment: @insolor но правильный ответ 2, значит должно быть еще что то

Comment: @insolor, правильный ответ - *2*. Множество - *{3, 6}*.

Answer (score 2):

Код не работает потому что `a` не множество и оператор `in` к нему не применим. Нужно уметь перебирать множества, чтобы решить эту задачу перебором. Но есть способ проще.

Разложим формулу *¬(¬(x ∈ A) ∧ (x ∈ {3, 6, 9, 12})) ∨ ¬(x ∈ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6})* на части:

*¬(¬F<sub>1</sub> ∧ F<sub>2</sub>) ∨ ¬F<sub>3</sub>*, где

*F<sub>1</sub> ≡ x ∈ A*, *F<sub>2</sub> ≡ x ∈ {3, 6, 9, 12}*, *F<sub>3</sub> ≡ x ∈ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}*.

Таблица истинности для новой формулы:

> ```
> F1   F2   F3    значение новой формулы
>  f    f    f         t
>  f    f    t         t
>  f    t    f         t
>  f    t    t         f
>  t    f    f         t
>  t    f    t         t
>  t    t    f         t
>  t    t    t         t
> ```

Единственная строка когда формула ложна это *F<sub>1</sub>* ложно, *F<sub>2</sub>* истинно, *F<sub>3</sub>* истинно. Два последних утверждения истинны тогда и только тогда когда *x ∈ {3, 6, 9, 12} ∩ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}*. То есть когда *x ∈ {3, 6}*. В этой ситуации нужно не допустить чтобы *x ∈ A* оказалось ложно. Нет ничего проще: если *A* будет содержать числа *3* и  *6*, этого не будет.

Задачу решает любое множество *A*, которое содержит числа *3* и *6*. Минимальное по размеру решение *A = {3, 6}*.

Посмотрим на эту задачу с другой стороны. Предположим что в ответе будет множество содержащее число *13*. Наша формула даёт один и тот же результат для любых *x ≥ 13*. Значит вместе с *13* в ответ должны будут войти *14*, *15*, ... - все числа большие *13*. В ответе окажется бесконечное множество. Но в постановке задача есть намёк что множество *A* конечное. Тогда имеет смысл рассматривать только множества *A* в которых нет элементов больших двеннадцати. Устроим перебор таких множеств и будет проверять формулу на тождественность.

`r` перебирает мощность множества *A*, `c` перебирает сами такие множества, `x` перебирает элементы:

```
import itertools
                                                   

def search():
    s1 = {3, 6, 9, 12}
    s2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
    for r in range(13):
        for c in itertools.combinations(range(1, 13), r):
            a = set(c)
            
            # ¬(¬(x ∈ A) ∧ (x ∈ {3, 6, 9, 12})) ∨ ¬(x ∈ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}) 
            if all(
                not(not (x in a) and (x in s1)) or not (x in s2)
                for x in range(1, 13)
            ):
                return a


print(search())
```

> ```
> $ python search-a.py
> {3, 6}
> ```

Comment: Если не ограничивать множество А диапазоном от 1 до 12 (в задаче такого ограничения нет), то подвыражение `not (x in s2)` будет истинно для любых `x>6`, что приведет к истинности всего выражения. И ответ будет 1. Думаю, что что-то не так в условии задачи.

Comment: @АлексейР, я пытался убедить читателя что числа от 13 и больше принадлежат или не принадлежат минимальному *A* одновременно. С условиями всё в порядке.